# Does anyone know where I can find the Microsoft VSMT ? (Virtual Server Migration Toolkit)

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v

All the links on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/bb545897.aspx seem to be broken.

Comment: r u doing v2v or p2v? Also do you mean the version that worked with virtual server 2005?  Hope not since thats older then the hills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use that, it doesn't work with [Hyper-V](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/hyper-v-server/default.aspx) (if you're still running Virtual Server you'd better be planning an upgrade, soon). The [SysInternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) includes Disk2VHD, which can do the conversion, though you'll likely have to [muck with the disk drivers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314082/en-us) or the virtualized system will not boot (you'll end up with a STOP 7B.

The general steps for using Disk2VHD:

1. Run `chkdsk /x` and `defrag` on the drive(s) you're going to convert.
2. Muck with the IDE settings. There are MergeIDE programs and websites to help guide you through this if the KB article above isn't clear enough. It's a pain to do this after the next step, so do it here.
3. Run the Disk2VHD program, create the VHD files.
4. Copy the VHD files to your Hyper-V host (KVM can convert VHDs, and Xen uses them natively as well). Create the VMs pointing to the VHDs and try to get the virtual hardware as similar to the physical as possible.
5. Install the Hyper-V Integration Services (paravirtualization drivers). Switch Emulated NICs to Synthetic (only if you had emulated installed to get the networking going before HIS.

If you're going to be doing this on multiple machines I'd recommend a fully automated tool. Microsoft provides this functionality in SCVMM, which you can download a free trial of too. There are other utilities out there, Acronis and others.

<sub>Full Disclosure: I work for an MS Partner</sub>